# Generated Model gives 501 when trying to use the delete on the rest api

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I created a model using the command:
   slc loopback:model

I did not change anything else, so the model.js is default and the model.json is default. the model is exposed over the rest api and shows up in the api explorer.
If I run a GET it returns the 3 coffeeshops as required, then when I try and DELETE one of those shops, either through the explorer or CURL, I get a 501 status code.
I have been reading documentation all day and nothing tells me that the deleteById call would be disabled, only the deleteAll call.
Am I missing something? Should I enable deletes for my custom models somewhere? I have extended the User Model and running a delete against that works 100%

Here is a screenshot of the api explorer and the returned 501 error. You can see that I am passing the id and it simply returns 501. The second image shows the console output.

[image: You can see the error occuring here]

[image: Console Output]

As Requested here is my coffee-shop.json

```
{
  "name": "CoffeeShop",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "city": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

And the model-config.json

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "CoffeeShop": {
    "dataSource": "oracleDS",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

Oh and my npm version is 3.10.8
node v6.9.1
and slc --version

```
strongloop v6.0.3 (node v6.9.1)
├── strong-arc@1.8.9 (3dd25ac)
├── strong-build@2.1.2 (a98f310)
├── strong-deploy@3.1.4 (9b29df0)
├── strong-mesh-models@8.1.0 (62e539b)
├── strong-pm@5.2.3
├── strong-registry@1.1.6 (f8c2339)
├── strong-start@1.3.4 (28c261d)
├─┬ strong-supervisor@3.3.3
│ └── strong-agent@2.1.1 (b51fc45)
├── generator-loopback@1.25.0 (6a0e2c0)
├── node-inspector@0.7.4
└── nodefly-register@0.3.3
```

Comment: That's weird, can you show `CoffeeShops.json` and `model-config.json` files ? Normally, this API call should return `200` `{count: 1}`

Comment: Very weird, I have added the two files. I am getting this behavior in my project but went back to the coffee shop sample and it is there as well.

Comment: Looks like it's coming from the Oracle datasource, the rest looks good to me. Are you performing an autoupdate/automigrate in a boot script ?

Comment: I tested it today with db and got the same result :-( 501 Not implemented. The problem comes from the CORS call to OPTIONS. For a Delete it seems not to allow CORS. I started getting the same problem on a POST when I changed the content-type to application/json. When I go live my api and Angular client will be served from the same URL so CORS will be out of the picture, at the moment during dev the Angular is running on my machine. I had the autoupdate in the server.js script but I have removed them because they were giving issues. I just create script files to migrate manually when I deploy.

Comment: Oh, and the CORS settings in the middleware are at their default of true, I have not played with them.

Comment: It's weird that the problem is related to CORS because also in dev you serve the angular with the server right ?

Comment: Could you run the server with [debug strings](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Setting-debug-strings.html) `set DEBUG=loopback:datasource,loopback:strong-remoting:* && node .` (windows) or `DEBUG=loopback:datasource,loopback:strong-remoting:* node .` (Unix) ? It should help understand further what is going on

Comment: OK This is very weird. I had tried the DEBUG strings before, but only the datasource not the remoting string so I thought I would try it quickly and the DELETE is working now. The only major changes I have made to the code is adding a few more models, but I had to reboot my laptop and the server is VM so that got rebooted as well. Even the CoffeeShops demo is deleting again with no changes to that API. I am really confused with why it would start working again? The only thing that could have solved this is the reboot.